# Large Commutative diagram going beyond the margins

Tags: margins

I am writing a latex document and while writing a commutative diagram using the tikz environment, the width of the compiled diagram is beyond the width of the rest of the text. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\makeatletter
% these two slashes-commands for continuous chapter numbering in parts of the document
\makeatother
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\bf} %for chapter headings
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} % and in the above line to use commutative diagrams
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
% below four lines to just one or two cyrillic letter
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{wncy}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wncy}{m}{n}{<->wncyr10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mcy}{U}{wncy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sh}{\mathord}{mcy}{"58} 
 %Cyrillic letter command over
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix} % to make appendi appear in the table of contents
 \usepackage{amssymb}  %to use direct sum symbol
 \usepackage{graphicx} %toinsert images
 \usepackage{amsmath} %to use matrices
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{bm} % to use bold font in math mode use \bm{ insert math mode text}
 \usepackage{mathrsfs} %for scripted english characters
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{tikz-cd} % to draw commutative diagrams
 \usepackage{enumitem}

All this can be combined in the following:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  0 \arrow{r} & 
\frac{E'(K)}{\phi(E(K))} \arrow{r}{\delta} \arrow{d} &
H^{1}(G_K, E[\phi]) \arrow{r} \arrow{d}{Res_v} &
WC(E/K)[\phi] \arrow{r} \arrow{d} & 0 \\
0 \arrow{r} &
\frac{E'(K_v)}{\phi(E(K_v))} \arrow{r}{\delta_{v}} \arrow{d} &
H^{1}(G_{v}, E[\phi]) \arrow{r} \arrow{d} & 
WC(E/K_{v})[\phi] \arrow{r} \arrow{d} & 0 \\
0 \arrow{r} & 
\prod\limits_{v \in M_K} \frac{E'(K_v)}{\phi(E(K_v))} \arrow{r}{\prod\limits_{v \in M_K}\delta_{v}} &
\prod\limits_{v \in M_K} H^{1}(G_{v}, E[\phi]) \arrow{r} &
\prod\limits_{v \in M_K} WC(E/K_{v})[\phi] \arrow{r} & 0 
\tag{$**$} 
\label{starstar}
\end{tikzcd}  
\]
\end{document}
```

It would be great if someone could help me in this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fit your diagram in text width you should take two measured:

- reduce distance between nodes
- use smaller font
- use `\mathclap` from the `mathtools` package for writing limits of products:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{starstar}
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=1.8em, font=\small]
0 \ar{r} & \frac{E'(K)}{\phi(E(K))} \ar{r}{\delta} \ar{d} 
    & H^{1}(G_K, E[\phi]) \ar{r} \ar{d}{Res_v} & WC(E/K)[\phi] \ar{r} \ar{d} & 0 \\
0 \ar{r} & \frac{E'(K_v)}{\phi(E(K_v))} \ar{r}{\delta_{v}} \ar{d} 
    & H^{1}(G_{v}, E[\phi]) \ar{r} \ar{d} & WC(E/K_{v})[\phi] \ar{r} \ar{d} & 0 \\
0 \ar{r} & \prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}} \frac{E'(K_v)}{\phi(E(K_v))} 
            \ar{r}{\prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}}\delta_{v}} 
    &
\prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}} H^{1}(G_{v}, E[\phi]) \ar{r} &
\prod\limits_{\mathclap{v \in M_K}} WC(E/K_{v})[\phi] \ar{r} & 0
\end{tikzcd}  
\tag{$**$}
    \end{equation}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting the following error: Package pgfkeys error on using the above code. More details: ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/sep' and I am going to ig
nore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.

Comment: I removed 'sep=1.8em' from your code and the rest of the it is working perfectly, the only difference is that the tag $**$ is right below the diagram instead of on the right side to it. But that's not a big problem. Thank you again!

Comment: @Shreya, I select `sep=1.8em` that tag `(**)` can be inline with diagram. MWE is tested with recent MIkTeX installation. If you use `Overleaf` then can happen that there are older version of packages which doesn't work as expected. Try to use `column sep` instead of `sep`.

Comment: I am using a really old installation of TeXmaker with TexLive. And what you suggested is still not working though. I appreciate the help though. Thanks~

Comment: @Shreya, try to update your LaTeX installation. As far as I read in site, now is available version TexLive 2020.